# How does Selenium drag and drop functionality work under the hood?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to automate drag and drop functionality on my simple html site (saved in a file). The drag and drop functionality works if I manually drag the image to the drag box. But, if I try and replicate the same flow with Python and Selenium, the image is not dragged to the target element. How exactly does the drag and drop work under the hood? Am I missing something in my html file? I'm certain my Selenium code is correct, it works on other sites.

```
source_element = driver.find_element_by_id('image')
target_element = driver.find_element_by_id('drag-box')
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source_element, target_element).perform()
```

```
<head>

    <title>Test Site</title>

    <style>

        #drag-box, #dummy-box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid;
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: left;
        }

    </style>

    <script>

        function allowDrop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData("image", event.target.id);
        }

        function drop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("image");
            event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <header class="header-content">

        <h1>Welcome to the site!</h1>

    </header>

    <main class="main-content">

        <img id="image" src="test-image.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">

    </main>

    <div id="dummy-box"></div>
    <div id="drag-box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

The file is opened in my browser and elements are found, but nothing happens when I execute drag and drop. I tried on both Firefox and Chrome. Also, both browsers and webdrivers are up to date.

Comment: I believe it moves the cursor, clicks and holds, moves the cursor and releases the click.  I'm assuming it does not generate dragstart, dragend, or drop events, because it just plain doesn't work for markup like this.   Also see this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604135/why-this-seleniums-drag-and-drop-c-sharp-code-is-not-working-on-chrome/56615037#56615037

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks the issue was the html 5 implementation of drag and drop. It works when I use jQuery instead.