# Drag_and_drop does nothing

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I'm having no luck at all getting ActionChains actions to work in Chrome, specifically drag_and_drop, and I'm not finding any workarounds.

In my case, I'm dealing with an issue where a table of data will only appear once an element is dragged into a certain field. If I try to do this with ActionChains, the program simply does nothing and hangs.

This is using selenium in python.

I'm in Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100

Here's a snippet of example code that should recreate the situation:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time
import re

### Start Process
# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp')


dragged = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="drag1"]')
dropped = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div2"]')
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(dragged, dropped).perform()
```

This code should just drag the logo from the left box to the right, but it does nothing.

*Edit:* Here's what gets returned in the shell:

```
 DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54994/devtools/browser/a9093d6c-8ee0-4140-84fe-dd3009412fbc
 [14976:20964:0710/120727.552:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
 [14976:20964:0710/120727.576:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
 Press any key to continue . . . [14976:20964:0710/120736.634:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)]
 handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

Comment: post the markup... if it depends on ondragover and ondrop events, it won't work (currently draganddrop action only generates mousedown/mouseup).  You'll need to use javascript to generate the events.  Also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604135/why-this-seleniums-drag-and-drop-c-sharp-code-is-not-working-on-chrome/56615037#56615037

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks, I'll edit the post and see if I can get it to execute the javascript

Comment: @pcalkins I can't get your solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604135/why-this-seleniums-drag-and-drop-c-sharp-code-is-not-working-on-chrome/56615037#56615037  to work here. I converted the syntax (external to the string) to python and tried to call it using driver.execute_script(simulateFunction + "\n simulateDragDrop(dragged, dropped);", dragged, dropped) but it won't recognize the inputs. Could you provide an answer showing how to successfully implement this in python?

Comment: I do not know any Python.  Basically I'm defining the todrag and todrop elements at the end of the string....("drag1" and "div2" are specific ids for the W3Cschools page in the question) so the last two lines there you need to put in your id for the element you are dragging and the element you are dropping to...  (hopefully they have ids...)  the call to the function remains the same  because those vars are defined.  So it injects the utility function along two statements declaring the variables and then it calls the function with those declared variables (they are elements).

Comment: so basically you don't need the args there... you're just injecting the script as a string.  Modify the var definitions only... the function call remains "simulateDragDrop(toDrag, toDrop);"  You could just combine them into one string if you like.  You should also post the markup, because this might not be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

@pcalkins Got it! here's the working code! I just moved that last line in the string that declared the variables into the function call so I could change it in different situations. Thanks so much!

```
from selenium import webdriver

#javaScript function to drag and drop
simulateFunction = str("function simulateDragDrop(sourceNode, destinationNode) {\n" +
"    var EVENT_TYPES = {\n" +
"        DRAG_END: 'dragend',\n" +
"        DRAG_START: 'dragstart',\n" +
"        DROP: 'drop'\n" +
"    }\n" +
"\n" +
"    function createCustomEvent(type) {\n" +
"        var event = new CustomEvent(\"CustomEvent\")\n" +
"        event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null)\n" +
"        event.dataTransfer = {\n" +
"            data: {\n" +
"            },\n" +
"            setData: function(type, val) {\n" +
"                this.data[type] = val\n" +
"            },\n" +
"            getData: function(type) {\n" +
"                return this.data[type]\n" +
"            }\n" +
"        }\n" +
"        return event\n" +
"    }\n" +
"\n" +
"    function dispatchEvent(node, type, event) {\n" +
"        if (node.dispatchEvent) {\n" +
"            return node.dispatchEvent(event)\n" +
"        }\n" +
"        if (node.fireEvent) {\n" +
"            return node.fireEvent(\"on\" + type, event)\n" +
"        }\n" +
"    }\n" +
"\n" +
"    var event = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START)\n" +
"    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START, event)\n" +
"\n" +
"    var dropEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DROP)\n" +
"    dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer\n" +
"    dispatchEvent(destinationNode, EVENT_TYPES.DROP, dropEvent)\n" +
"\n" +
"    var dragEndEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END)\n" +
"    dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer\n" +
"    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END, dragEndEvent)\n" +
"}; ")

### Start Process
# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp')

#call javascript dragdrop function
#here, drag1 and div2 are the page-specific IDs of the item to drag and the place to drop it, respectively.
driver.execute_script(simulateFunction + "var toDrag =document.getElementById('drag1'); var toDrop = document.getElementById('div2'); simulateDragDrop(toDrag, toDrop);")
```

Comment: good to hear!  I also pass in the values for my own function... so in Java it becomes, ""var toDrag =document.getElementById('"+ this.Variable1 + "drag1');...""