# Drag and Drop in robot framework

Tags: javascript, selenium, drag-and-drop, robotframework

i've found several response about htis topic but almost the totality of them alre older at least of 2 years and for me doesn't work.

So I'm asking again: how can i do the drag and drop? Maybe, it could be done by using an easy javascript, but i'm literally at 0 with js.

What I've tried:

Using the SeleniumLibrary Keyword "Drag and drop" and "Drag and drop by offset".

In both of the case i can see that my webelement (a div) is clicked and moved but i cannot see the animation and most important it is not "released".

Also i've tried by coding a keyword (as suggested in some so responses) but it doesn't work: robot framework tells me the test is passed, by the way the drag and drop has not been done.
The keyword i coded is the following:

```
Drag And Drop Personal
[Arguments]    ${xpath1}    ${xpath2}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      5x     5s      SeleniumLibrary.Mouse Down   ${xpath1}

Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      5x     5s      SeleniumLibrary.Mouse Over   ${xpath2}

Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      5x     5s     SeleniumLibrary.Mouse Up     ${xpath2}
```

I'm stuck at this, someone can help? Thanks a lot

Comment: basically it depends on the site's implementation of the drag and drop.   The webdrivers generally don't generate the HTML5 events for drag/drop.   See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975681/drag-and-drop-does-nothing

Comment: @pcalkins, thaanks a lot for your reply. The problem is that i'm not confident with js and i'm trying to make it work, but cannot. Can you give me any suggestion about how to import a .js file and execute the script inside in robot framework? thanks a lot

Comment: not familiar with Robot framework.  The script will generate events on elements you get via javascript.  See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp