# Selenium drag and drop for Avery Design & Print (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm creating a python script to automate labels through "Avery Design & Print Online", using the 18160 template and importing a ".csv" file for the mail merge.

https://www.avery.com/templates/18160

Starting from the URL above, the script can

- Login
- Select the "blank" horizontal design
- Click "Data Mail Merge"
- Ask user for their ".csv" data file
- Modify the selected ".csv" file to match the requirements for Avery Design & Print
- IMPORT the newly generated ".csv" to perform mail merge.
- Create a text box containing "Last Name, First Name" and "DOB" (Date of Birth)
- Create a text box containing "Samples" and "Client Site"
- Resize the text boxes
- Open the QR codes prompt to add a barcode
- Go through prompts to bring up the window where I can add the "Samples" column as the barcode data by dragging and dropping.

The issue that I'm having is that I am unable to use the "drag and drop" command in Selenium to properly drag and drop my selection ("Samples") into the required input field.

When running the script, I get no errors from the drag and drop command but it doesn't do anything on the webpage. Instead, script times out when trying to click the "Finish" button, because that element will become unclickable when the drag and drop doesn't properly place the draggable field into the droppable input field. However, the drag and drop command IS working on lines in my script that resize the text boxes (which is done outside of any prompt windows).

[The "Samples" element is draggable, but using the drag and drop command does nothing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7HTl.png)

[Here are the web elements for the drag and drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsQng.png)

So far, I've tried:

- Using javascript to perform the drag and drop. (w/CSS selectors to find element)
- Using CSS selectors to find element
- Use "send_keys" on the input to type 'Samples', but this just makes the barcode equal to "SAMPLES" instead of each actual sample number.
- Using a series of commands instead of just "drag and drop"
- Using different parts of the draggable and droppable elements to find them
- I've also considered iframe issues, but the web elements are not under any iframes.
- Webdriverwait for explicit wait
- "time.sleep" command for implicit wait
- "seletools" package (https://pypi.org/project/seletools/)
- Selenium IDE to see if it generates anything different from my code. (It did not. It recorded my action as a drag and drop command. When running the code from Selenium IDE, it produces the same issue.)

Here is the snippet from my script that is failing.

```
InputBox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#barcode-code-128 > div:nth-child(2) > input')
DragField = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#modal-view-ex-container > div > div > div.dpo8-add-barcode > '
                                                 'div.merge-part > div.mail-merge-part > div.dpo8-mail-merge-list > '
                                                 'div:nth-child(1) > div')
time.sleep(5)
action.drag_and_drop(DragField, InputBox)

DispTextCheckbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="show-text-code-128"]'))
)
DispTextCheckbox.click()
GrNextButton2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="modal-view-ex-container"]/div/div/div[3]/div/button[3]'))
)
GrNextButton2.click()
```

[This is after the script times out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64WNL.png)

This is the timeout error I'm seeing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH\test.py", line 257, in <module>
    GrNextButton2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
  File "PATH\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Last thing, I will note that this seems to be an issue with this specific website/prompt. I've seen a lot of workarounds for a drag and drop bug in Selenium but none of them have changed anything and I am running into the same exact issue. I don't know if anyone might have a better understanding of what could be going on considering that this seems to be specific to this website, but I am new to scripting so maybe I'm missing something.

The web elements ARE being FOUND, but the command does nothing. The command IS running properly, but nothing is happening on the webpage. The drag and drop DOES seem to work OUTSIDE of any prompted windows on the webpage. Ultimately, I think the issue is the "prompt" window on the webpage, but I can't figure out how to get Selenium to work with it for drag and drop.

If anyone wants to help test, let me know if you need anything from me. Thanks in advance.

TL;DR - ["Avery Design & Print Online" will not allow me to drag and drop "Samples" into the input field when using Selenium.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7HTl.png)

Comment: HTML5 drag/drop events aren't generated by Selenium... (or at least they didn't used to be... been a while since I've tackled this).  You can execute Javascript to add those events.  Check here for script:  https://gist.github.com/druska/624501b7209a74040175  Also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975681/drag-and-drop-does-nothing/56993340#56993340

Comment: @pcalkins I implemented the javascript to no avail. Javascript runs succesfully, but there is still nothing happening on the webpage. I've also used the "seletools" package which accomplishes the same task I believe, and that has had the same result.

Comment: As an update. I decided to make this drag and drop process a manual process that has to be completed by the user.  For some reason this website wouldn't work.