# Selenium/Blazor: Drag And Drop elements from one list to another (C#)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to drag and drop one element to another.
[image]

I already red a lot questions/answers in stackoverflow, followed videos/tutorials but nothing seem to help.

**This is the DragAndDrop code:**

```
        public void DragAndDrop(string sourceLocator, string destinationLocator)
        {
           var sourceLocatorId = _webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(sourceLocator));
           var destinationLocatorId = _webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(destinationLocator));

           var action = new Actions(_webDriver);
           action.ClickAndHold(sourceLocatorId);
           action.MoveToElement(destinationLocatorId);
           action.Release(destinationLocatorId);
           action.Build();
           action.Perform();
        }
```

I dont get any fail/error messages, it does run through all code lines and the test passes without moving that mentioned element.

**This is the inspect of the**

1. SourceLocator (Im using **//div[@class='mud-drop-zone rounded flex-grow-1 py-4 pa-4']**)
   [image]
2. DestinationLocator (Im using **//div[@class='mud-drop-item']/..**)
   [image]

I tried a lot different locators, maybe im using still the wrong ones, but i cant figure out which i should take.

Comment: For HTML5 click and drag Selenium may not trigger the correct events.  Try the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975681/drag-and-drop-does-nothing/56993340#56993340

Comment: Okay im seeing its a javascript. Ill try to implement it