# Selenium: DragAndDrop in selenium not working in chrome (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to simulate a **DragAndDrop** during selenium automation tests in chrome.

AFAIK, the DragAndDrop methods provided by selenium are not working anymore because of different reasons (HTML5, Chrome not supporting it anymore?!)

So im now looking for a work around by using a **Java Script**.

I already went through all the DragAndDrop topics in here, but most of the solutions are from years ago and do not really give me a answer.

There is this one answer which has a Java Script in one of the older questions:
[Drag_and_drop does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975681/drag-and-drop-does-nothing/56993340#56993340)

I tried the java script directly in **"google chrome - inspect - console"** and modified it a bit but im still getting too many errors (see code below). I assume the errors appear because of the many chrome updates in the past.

I appreciate any help!

Source element id: **ATest_DragDropElement**

Destination element id: **ATest_DropZone**

```
function simulateDragDrop(sourceNode, destinationNode) {
                  var EVENT_TYPES = {DRAG_END: 'dragend',DRAG_START: 'dragstart',DROP: 'drop'};
                  function createCustomEvent(type) {
                      var event = new CustomEvent('CustomEvent');
                      event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null);
                      event.dataTransfer = 
                      {
                          data: {},
                          setData: function(type, val) {this.data[type] = val;},
                          getData: function(type) {return this.data[type];},
                          files: {},
                          items: {}
                      };
                      return event;
                  };
                  function dispatchEvent(node, type, event) {
                      if (node.dispatchEvent) {
                          return node.dispatchEvent(event);
                      }
                      if (node.fireEvent) {
                          return node.fireEvent('on' + type, event);
                      }
                  };
                  var event = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START);
                  dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START, event);
                  var dropEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DROP);
                  dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
                  dispatchEvent(destinationNode, EVENT_TYPES.DROP, dropEvent);
                  var dragEndEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END);
                  dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
                  dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END, dragEndEvent);
               };

var sourceNode = document.getElementById("ATest_DragDropElement");
var destinationNode = document.getElementById("ATest_DropZone");

simulateDragDrop(sourceNode, destinationNode);
```

Screenshot of the element in inspect
[image]

Screenshot of the console.logs from the js execution:
[image]

Comment: it'll depend on the site, but I think in general if there's an event handler that's looking for "ondragstart", or "ondragend", you need to fire javascript to create a custom event. Usually actions' "dragAndDropBy" method works, though. That takes an element, and x and y offsets. Can you include more of the DOM markup and which elements have the drag/drop handlers?

Answer (score 0):

for selenium you can try dispatching raw event using mouse events.

Providing selenium JavaScript implementation.
Here is the code that you can try:

Function to call (note dispatchDND is string function, you can find it below)

> ```
> async function dragAndDropEvent(selectorDrag: string, selectorDrop: string | null, options: any = {}) {
>     return driver.executeScript(dispatchDND, selectorDrag, selectorDrop, options);
> }
> ```

Parameters legend:

> selectorDrag: CSS Selector of drag element

> selectorDrop: Css Selector of drop element. If you want to drop element in
> a specified position just send null as second argument.

> options: Here you can set [dragElemIndex] option
> if there are more than one element that match [selectorDrag]. One more
> option is [makeDraggable: true] if you want to make [selectorDrag] element
> draggable. [dropLocation] Use dropLocation.x dropLocation.y dropLocation.z for specific coordinates wheer to place the element.

Native js function to execute the drag and drop.

```
const dispatchDND = `function dragAndDrop(selectorDrag, selectorDrop, options) {

    let elemDrag, elemDrop;

    if (!selectorDrag) {
        throw new Error('Error! Element [selectorDrop] selector not defined.');
    }

    if (!options) {
        throw new Error('Options not specified! Please add options or just send <{}>.');
    }

    if (options.dragElemIndex != undefined) {
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selectorDrag);
        elemDrag = elements[options.dragElemIndex];
    } else {
        elemDrag = document.querySelector(selectorDrag);
    }

    elemDrop = (selectorDrop === null && options.dropLocation) ? null : document.querySelector(selectorDrop);

    if (options.makeDraggable)
         makeDraggable(elemDrag);

    function makeDraggable(elm) {
        elm.draggable = true;
    }

    if (elemDrag === undefined || elemDrag === null) {
        throw new Error('Error!Cannot get element with specified selector.');
    }

    function fireMouseEvent(type, elem, dataTransfer) {
        const evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, elem);
        if (/^dr/i.test(type)) {
            evt.dataTransfer = dataTransfer || createNewDataTransfer();
        }
        (elem === null) ? document.body.dispatchEvent(evt) : elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    function createNewDataTransfer() {
        let data = {};
        return {
            clearData: function(key) {
                if (key === undefined) {
                    data = {};
                } else {
                    delete data[key];
                }
            },
            getData: function(key) {
                return data[key];
            },
            setData: function(key, value) {
                data[key] = value;
            },
            setDragImage: function() {},
            dropEffect: 'none',
            files: [],
            items: [],
            types: [],
        };
    }

    function mouseMove() {
        const evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        if (elemDrop === null) {
            evt.initMouseEvent('mousemove', true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, options.dropLocation.x,
             options.dropLocation.y, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        } else {
             evt.initMouseEvent('mousemove', true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, false, false, false,
                false, 0, elemDrop);
        }
        if (/^dr/i.test('mousemove')) {
            evt.dataTransfer = dataTransfer || createNewDataTransfer();
        }
        (elemDrop === null) ? document.body.dispatchEvent(evt) : elemDrop.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    function drop() {
        if (elemDrop === null) {
            const evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initMouseEvent('mouseup', true, true, window, 1, options.dropLocation.x, options.dropLocation.y,
                options.dropLocation.x, options.dropLocation.y, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            document.body.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else {
            fireMouseEvent('mouseup', elemDrop);
        }

    }

    fireMouseEvent('mousedown', elemDrag);
    mouseMove();
    drop();

    return true;
}

dragAndDrop(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
`;
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide me the piece of code, that i can simply test directly in the Browser when going to Inspect-Console? I can execute js there and see if the script works. My CSSSelectors are: [id='ATest_DragDropElement'] and [id='ATest_DropZone']

Comment: Use the code wrapped in string variable dispatchDND. Everything is function and declare them in the browser console.
After that use dragAndDrop function with relevant parameters to test.

Comment: I was able to execute the code successfully in the chrome console and the result is "true", but the selectorDrag element didnt move at all. Any idea what i could do next?

Comment: I added a console.log for elemDrop and elemDrag, both can be found. I uploaded a screenshot of the logs above

Comment: Its possible nested element in <div> to accept the events, and/or being triggered by other events. Solution provided above is using mouse events. so its weird.