# Selenium: Drag and Drop functionality with pyautoGUI working on Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, drag-and-drop

I study a lot of thing regarding python automation, reached a point that i proposed to make scripts to test https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/ using selenium and python. At the Drag and Drop section everting i found was using specific JS scripts or answers that the specific functionality does not work. My mind grinded at this and got the below solution that is working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.set_window_size(800, 450)

win_size = driver.get_window_size()

source = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#column-a")
target = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#column-b")

element_size = source.size

source_location = source.location
target_location = target.location

inner_width = driver.execute_script("return window.innerWidth;")
inner_height = driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight;")

offset_width = win_size['width'] - inner_width + element_size['width'] / 2
offset_height = win_size['height'] - inner_height + element_size['height'] / 2

# ### Print Statememts used for Debbug ###
# print(f"actual size is {win_size} ,ineer size is {inner_width}, {inner_height}")
# print(source_location, target_location)
# print(element_size, f"the offsets are {offset_width} and {offset_height}")

pyautogui.moveTo(source_location['x'] + offset_width, source_location['y'] + offset_height)
pyautogui.mouseDown()

pyautogui.moveTo(target_location['x'] + offset_width, target_location['y'] + offset_height, duration=3)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

# ###  Assertion to check in case you dont wanna look and just run the test ###
# ###  Find the moved item, get the new location  ###
# ###  Assert that initial location and location after move are not the same => Drag and Drop action is a success  ###
# source_moved = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="column"]/header[text()="A"]')
# source_newlocation = source_moved.location
# assert source_location != source_newlocation

time.sleep(1)

driver.quit()
```

Now i know it might look simple and beginner-ish but i'm still learning and developing my skill set this is my solution that works.

Before this i have tried all the the classic drag and drop listed in selenium documentation like :

- drag_and_drop(source, target)
- drag_and_drop_by_offset(source, x_offset, y_offset)
- performing chained click_and_hold(element), move_by_offset(xOffset, yOffset), pause(sec) and release() methods
- performing chained click_and_hold(element), move_to_element(target), pause(sec), move_by_offset(xOffset, yOffset) and release() methods
- tried various shenanigans to get the mouse location while making selenium click (click and hold, right click, etc.. on the specific element
  All of the above avenues did not work. Only solution provided was the use of JS script that is run inside the python file used for selenium

**PS. Make sure that Scale setting from Display Settings is at 100% or it will mess up the positions.**

Comment: Did you try drag and drop using JS mouse events? I have write similar answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77486950/selenium-draganddrop-in-selenium-not-working-in-chrome-c/77487690#77487690
Note: selenium commands are for Javascript, just change to relevant in pyton.

Comment: @Infern0 i made it work with JS function but i was looking for a way to make it work without JS and bypass the issue that conventional drag and drop had in selenium, i searched a lot about it and dint find any solution that is using pyautogui to do the actual drag and drop by performing mouse actions.

Comment: Hi @dbeniamin, under the hood can work similar with JS events, or sending specific Chromium/selenium instructions to the browser. On top each framework is using this kind of functions. So using different frameworks/tools can lead to using the same instructions or simliar thing for the same operation. To be sure its working and as close as possible to real user, follow up the suggested tools and if they dont work, try with something as close as possible to implementation. JS events are such example.