# Selenium Python - drag and drop not working into field

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver latest version and I need to drag and drop link a element into anotation field from CKeditor, but it is not IFrame. From my previous testing, it was working with Java and Selenium2 with FF47 by Robot drag and drop function.

Now, I need to do this action with latest version of Selenium with Python3. I put this verified code, which should work, but it will stuck my mouse with holding element with dragged link, so the rest of the test will pass with holding title link, which is not dropped into CKeditor, but when I simulate mouse click into anotation field, it will become active from operation, but the holding element will not dropped into. Only manual mouse click will drop the link into anotation and resets the mouse holding. Tested with Ubuntu 18.04 amd64 Firefox 70 and GChrome 77 - same results.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL)
alink_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath(TITLE)
anotation_body = driver.find_element_by_xpath(TFIELD)
# 1. alternative
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(alink_from, anotation_body).click(anotation_body).perform()
# 2. alternative
ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(alink_from).move_to_element(anotation_body).release().click(anotation_body).perform()
```

Also tried pressing Enter key, double mouse click, moving by offset, reseting actions, switch into frame, Javascript clicking - nothing works, still same. Can someone help me with this operation please? Mouse is still holding the dragged element until the test ends or I will manualy click somewhere.

Comment: Is the element above or below the location where it is being dragged and dropped too?

Comment: CKEditor probably uses HTML5 drag events. (dragstart/dragend which, the last time I checked, webdriver does not generate... ) Maybe try this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604135/why-this-seleniums-drag-and-drop-c-sharp-code-is-not-working-on-chrome/56615037#56615037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I tried everything mostly with Javascript solution. Tried simulateDragDrop with element or ID selector, tried simulateDragDrop with JQuery, tried executeAsync for JQuery and nothing happened. Tried this for even other drag and drop case and not it was not working.

Nearest solution was JS drag and drop, which drags the element, but it wont drop that: 
https://ynot408.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/drag-and-drop-using-selenium-webdriver/

```
driver.execute_script(js + "simulate(arguments[0],'mousedown',0,0);",alink_from)
driver.execute_script(js + "simulate(arguments[0],'mousemove',arguments[1],arguments[2]);",alink_from,xto,yto)
driver.execute_script(js + "simulate(arguments[0],'mouseup',arguments[1],arguments[2]);",alink_from,xto,yto)
```

Finally after couple of hours I made a solution with using library PyAutoGUI! But that will need to get diffent coordinates, because PyAutoGUI using window coordinate and Selenium using browser coordinate. The problem is, that you need to focus on target element which will be dragged into target, but it will need to mouse Up the target and then click up to target.

Also this library will require install (on Ubuntu for example):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
pip3 install pyautogui
```

Here is the code:

```
import time
import pyautogui

height=driver.get_window_size()['height']
browser_navigation_panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
xf = alink_from.location['x']
yf = alink_from.location['y']
act_y_from = yf%height
scroll_Y_from= yf/height
try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, "+str(scroll_Y_from*height)+")")
except Exception as err:
    print("Exception")
pyautogui.moveTo(xf,act_y_from+browser_navigation_panel_height)

xto = anotation_body.location['x']
yto = anotation_body.location['y']
act_y_to = yto%height
scroll_Y_to = yto/height
pyautogui.dragTo(xto+1,act_y_to+browser_navigation_panel_height)
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.mouseUp()
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActionChains` perform the actions in the order they were inserted: clicking and holding the element, dropping it in the target field and only then clicking this field. If the field become active after the click do it first

```
ActionChains(driver).click(anotation_body).drag_and_drop(alink_from, anotation_body).perform()
# or
anotation_body.click()
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(alink_from, anotation_body).perform()
```